# Surfraw configuration files missing

Tags: command-line

I recently installed surfraw on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

surfraw documentation and web help suggests that these two configuration files should be present:

1. /etc/surfraw.conf
2. ~/.surfraw.conf

But neither are present on my PC. I tried removing surfraw and then installing again but didn't help. Does this mean surfraw isn't installing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed `surfraw` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install surfraw
```

Then the configuration file is by default in:

```
/etc/xdg/surfraw/conf
```

**Tip**: To find where a package will install files you can check this kind of page:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/surfraw/filelist

Comment: Does this conf file represent a system wide conf file or is it just specific to my account?

Comment: With your reputation level you can also vote on answers, just click on the ^ above the 0. Thanks.

Comment: This one is system wide